# Is it possible to replace an axis with a parasiteaxis?

Tags: matplotlib

I have code that requires a `ParasiteAxis` instance, or at least something with a `toggle_axisline` method, in order to function properly.  I'd like to be able to pass it any arbitrary axis created in any way (e.g., through a simple `plot` call).

How can I convert any given `axis` instance into a `ParasiteAxis` or `HostAxis` instance?

(for a specific use-case, see issue https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/pull/88 and specifically the workaround implemented in commit https://github.com/keflavich/aplpy/commit/02ecd5386f7d3a93ca8e60c3db2b34ff3216060a)